# How To Display Multiple Table Column Values in a Single Dropdown on a Razor Page?

Tags: asp.net, dropdown, razor-pages, cascadingdropdown

I'm not sure of the best way to go about this. I have one table. It is a list of Municipalities and their info. Name, address, phone, fax, email, etc. Right now, there is one row of data for each municipality.

However, each municipality can have multiple agencies. For example, City XYZ might have a City Council, Planning Commission and a Board of Appeals. Currently, I have columns in the Municipality table to hold those values as AssocAgencies1, AssocAgencies2, AssocAgencies3, etc. (So City Council would be in the AssocAgencies1 column, Planning Commission in the AssocAgencies2 column, etc.)

I would like to use this data to populate a table called Referrals. The form to add data to the referrals table wants the Municipality Name and the Agency from that Municipality that the referral is coming from. So, If a user selects City XYZ from a dropdown based on the Municpalities table name column (Municipalities.Name), I would like them then to be able to be provided another FILTERED dropdown that would list any agencies tied to City XYZ (in this example City Council, Planning Commission and a Board of Appeals).

Is it possible to pull those separate columns (Agency1, Agency2, Agency3) into one dropdown? Or should I be combining those agency values into one column as an array (City Council,Planning Commission,Board of Appeals). If that is the case, how would I separate those values into a dropdown (or even radio buttons would work), so that the Referral entry would record just the appropriate agency, not all of them.

Here is my current Municpality model:

```
namespace Referrals.Model
{
    public class Municipality
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name ="SWIS")]
        public string SWIS { get; set;}
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Municipality Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Combo Name: Name, Town/City/Village")]
        public string ComboName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Address 1")]
        public string? Addr1 { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Address 2")]
        public string? Addr2 { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "City")]
        public string? City { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "State")]
        public string? State { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Zip")]
        [DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
        public string? Zip { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([1-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid phone number")]
        public string? OfficePhone { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Fax Number")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([1-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid fax number")]
        public string? FaxNumber { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string? EmailAddress { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Website")]
        [DataType(DataType.Url)]
        public string? Website { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Associated Agencies")]
        public string? AssocAgencies1 { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Associated Agencies")]
        public string? AssocAgencies2 { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Associated Agencies")]
        public string? AssocAgencies3 { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Associated Agencies")]
        public string? AssocAgencies4 { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Associated Agencies")]
        public string? AssocAgencies5 { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Added/Updated By")]
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Date Added/Updated")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is a snip of the start of my Referral view page:

```
@page
@model Referrals.Pages.NewReferrals.CreateModel

<form method="post">
    <div class="border p-3 mt-4">
        <div class="row pb-2">
            <h2 class="text-primary pl-3">Add New Referral</h2>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>

    <table class="table table-bordeless" style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 15%">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label asp-for="Referral.RefNo"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Referral.RefNo" class="form-control"/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Referral.RefNo" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </td>    
            <td style="width: 10%">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label asp-for="Referral.RefSuffix"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Referral.RefSuffix" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Referral.RefSuffix" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 15%">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label asp-for="Referral.RefYear"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Referral.RefYear" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Referral.RefYear" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 15%">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label asp-for="Referral.RefNoComplete"></label>
                    // Need to figure out how to concatenate values for here of RefNo, RefSuffix and RefYear
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 15%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Referral.DateReceived"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Referral.DateReceived" type="date" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Referral.DateReceived" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 15%">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label asp-for="Referral.BoardMtgMonth"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Referral.BoardMtgMonth" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Referral.BoardMtgMonth" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 15%">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label asp-for="Referral.BoardMtgYear"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Referral.BoardMtgYear" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Referral.BoardMtgYear" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="table table-bordeless" style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 30%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Referral.RefMunicipality"></label>
                        <select asp-for="Referral.RefMunicipality" id="Select1" class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplayMuniName.OrderBy(x => x.Name),"Name", "Name"))"><option value="Name" selected disabled>---Select Referring Municipality---</option></select>
                    </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 25%">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    // Would like a dropdown here filtered on the previous dropdown
                    <label asp-for="Referral.RefAgencyName"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Referral.RefAgencyName" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Referral.RefAgencyName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
```

Any suggestions or points in the right direction would be sincerely appreciated.

My .cs for the create view:

```
using Referrals.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Referrals.Model;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Referrals.Pages.NewReferrals;

[BindProperties]

public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    public Referral Referral { get; set; }
    public CreateModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Municipality> DisplayMuniName { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        await _db.Referral.Select(a => a.RefMunicipality).ToListAsync();
        DisplayMuniName = await _db.Municipality.ToListAsync();

    }

    List<string> GetAgencies(int Id)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        var municipality = GetMunicipality(Id);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(municipality.AssocAgencies1))
        {
            result.Add(municipality.AssocAgencies1);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(municipality.AssocAgencies2))
        {
            result.Add(municipality.AssocAgencies2);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(municipality.AssocAgencies3))
        {
            result.Add(municipality.AssocAgencies3);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(municipality.AssocAgencies4))
        {
            result.Add(municipality.AssocAgencies4);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(municipality.AssocAgencies5))
        {
            result.Add(municipality.AssocAgencies5);
        }

        //.... add all other agencies

        return result;
    }


    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Referral.Add(Referral);
            await _db.Referral.AddAsync(Referral);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            TempData["success"] = "Referral added successfully.";
            return RedirectToPage("Index");
        }
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Complete .CS

```
using Referrals.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Referrals.Model;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Referrals.Pages.NewReferrals;

[BindProperties]

public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    private readonly IList<string> _agencies;
    public Referral Referral { get; set; }
    public CreateModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
    public CreateModel()
    {
        //.....
        _agencies = new List<string>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Municipality> DisplayMuniName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Calendar> DisplayCalendarMonth { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> DisplayAgencyName { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        // await _db.Referral.Select(a => a.RefMunicipality).ToListAsync();
        // DisplayMuniName = await _db.Municipality.ToListAsync();
        await _db.Referral.Select(a => a.BoardMtgMonth).ToListAsync();
        DisplayCalendarMonth = await _db.Calendar.ToListAsync();
        DisplayMuniName = _municipality;
        DisplayAgencyName = _agencies;
    }

    private List<string> FillAgencies(int id)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(municipality.AssocAgencies1))
        {
            result.Add(municipality.AssocAgencies1);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(municipality.AssocAgencies2))
        {
            result.Add(municipality.AssocAgencies2);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(municipality.AssocAgencies3))
        {
            result.Add(municipality.AssocAgencies3);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(municipality.AssocAgencies4))
        {
            result.Add(municipality.AssocAgencies4);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(municipality.AssocAgencies5))
        {
            result.Add(municipality.AssocAgencies5);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public JsonResult OnGetRetrieveAgencies(int id)
    {
        var agencies = FillAgencies(id);

        return new JsonResult(agencies);
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Referral.Add(Referral);
            await _db.Referral.AddAsync(Referral);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            TempData["success"] = "Referral added successfully.";
            return RedirectToPage("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            //reload the municipality
            DisplayMuniName = await _db.Municipality.ToListAsync();

            if (Referral.RefMunicipality !=0)
            {
                //if a municipality was selected reload the agencies
                DisplayAgencyName = FillAgencies(Referral.RefMunicipality);
            }

        }
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a *onChange* event handler for when a municipality is selected in the "Select1" drop down list, so that you can perform an ajax call to a *GET* method on the server that loads the agencies for the selected municipality. It is advisable to perform an ajax call so that you won't have to reload the whole page when selecting a municipality but only a portion of it (the drop down list with agencies). When the server method completes successfully, populate the agencies drop down list on the client side using *JavaScript*.
   You can find multiple examples on how to implement *ajax calls* with *razor pages*. [This is one](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/asp-net-core-razor-pages-how-to-implement-ajax-requests/)
2. On the server side, create the *GET* method that returns the list of agencies for the selected municipality. This is being called through *ajax*. I recommend using municipality Id, not municipality name because ids are unique. Imagine you have London (from UK) and London (from Ohio). They should be differentiated by Id, not by Name.

```
public async Task<JsonResult> OnGetRetrieveAgencies(int id)
{
    //build a list of agencies for the selected municipality
    var result = new List<string>();
    var municipality =  await _db.Municipality.SingleAsync(s=> s.Id == id);
    
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(municipality.AssocAgencies1))
    {
        result.Add(municipality.AssocAgencies1);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(municipality.AssocAgencies2))
    {
        result.Add(municipality.AssocAgencies2);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(municipality.AssocAgencies3))
    {
        result.Add(municipality.AssocAgencies3);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(municipality.AssocAgencies4))
    {
        result.Add(municipality.AssocAgencies4);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(municipality.AssocAgencies5))
    {
        result.Add(municipality.AssocAgencies5);
    }

    return new JsonResult(result);
}
```

On the view, make the following modifications:

1. use municipality id as value and municipality name as text

   ```
   <label asp-for="Referral.RefMunicipality"></label>
   <select asp-for="Referral.RefMunicipality" id="Select1" class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplayMuniName.OrderBy(x => x.Name),"Id", "Name"))"><option value="Name" selected disabled>---Select Referring Municipality---</    option></select>
   ```
2. add the agency drop down list

   Add auto selection for Agencies drop down list. We modify the select element:

   ```
   <label asp-for="Referral.RefAgencyName"></label>
   <select asp-for="Referral.RefAgencyName" id="SelectAgencies" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplayAgencyName.OrderBy(x => x)))"><option value="Name" selected disabled>--Please Select--</option></select>
   <span asp-validation-for="Referral.RefAgencyName" class="text-danger"></span>
   ```
3. Add the Scripts section after the closing form element with the JavaScript code that calls the server method and populates the agencies drop down list using jQuery Ajax. I've included some comments inline.

Let's use the agency name for both option text and option value. Remember, this is not ideal but, since we don't have an agency id, lets keep it like this. It helps us with the auto-selection.

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            
            $("#Select1").change(function(){
                var munId = $("#Select1 :selected").val();

                $.ajax({
                    //the url to call from the server. In this case it is a GET request. 
                    //Razor Pages needs a "handler" query string parameter with the value of the method from the server to be called
                    //from which you remove the "OnGet" prefix for GET methods or "OnPost" prefix for POST methods
                    //also add the selected municipality. If we have Id's there are always preferred as opposed to names because they should to be unique.
                    url: '/NewReferrals/Create?handler=RetrieveAgencies&id='+munId, 
                    type: 'GET',
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json"
                }).done(function(result) {
                    //this method gets called if the call to the server was successful
                    //bind the agencies drop down list here, on the client side, when the result is received from the server

                     var agenciesDropDown = $('#SelectAgencies');
                     agenciesDropDown.empty(); //clear the drop down list of the existing data
                     agenciesDropDown.append($("<option value=''>--Please Select--</option>")); //add default value

                     //the result is an array of agency names. 
                     // Iterate through the array using jquery's "each" and create options with (0, 'AgencyName 1'), (1, "Agency Name 2") etc
                     // Here again, we prefer to have the option value numeric (in this case we auto-assign an index 0,1,2..) 
                     // and the option text the actual display name
                     $.each(result, function(index, value) {
                        //agenciesDropDown.append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', index));
agenciesDropDown.append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', value));

                     });

                }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //this method gets called when there was an error in the response from the server
                    console.log("error:" + errorThrown);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

We will save the agencies on the server side as well to be able to preserve the selection if necessary. That is, if we have errors on the page, which means the ModelState is invalid. For this some refactoring is necessary.

1. In the code behind, add a new private field in the CreateModel class.

   ```
   private IList<string> _agencies;
   ```
2. In the constructor initialize the _agencies field:

   ```
   public CreateModel()
   {
    //.....
    _agencies = new List<string>();
   }
   ```
3. Add a public property that will encapsulate the private field:

   ```
   public IEnumerable<string> DisplayAgencyName
   {
      get; set;
   }
   ```
4. Initialize the property in the OnGet method:

   ```
   public async Task OnGet()
   {
       //.....
       DisplayMuniName = _municipality;
       DisplayAgencyName = _agencies;
   }
   ```
5. Extract the code that fills the agencies in a private method. It will be called both from `OnGetRetrieveAgencies` (through ajax) and `OnPost` when the ModelState is not valid.

   ```
   private List<string> FillAgencies(int id)
   {
       var result = new List<string>();

       //....add the rest of the code to fill the agencies
       return result;
   }

   public JsonResult OnGetRetrieveAgencies(int id)
   {
       var agencies = FillAgencies(id);

       return new JsonResult(agencies);
   }
   ```
6. Modify the `OnPost()` method to reload the Municipality and the Agencies drop down lists if the model state is not valid:

   ```
   public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
         //...code remains the same
       }
       else
       {
           //reload the municipality
           DisplayMuniName = await _db.Municipality.ToListAsync();

           if (Referral.RefMunicipality != 0)
           {
               //if a municipality was selected reload the agencies
               DisplayAgencyName = FillAgencies(Referral.RefMunicipality);
           }

       }
       return Page();
   }
   ```

**EDIT 2**

Remove second `CreateModel()`. Leave only the one that you have with ApplicationDbContext
In `OnGet`, uncomment your `await _db.Referral..` line and remove the last two lines.
Before the end of the method add `DisplayAgencyName = new List<string>();`
Modify FillAgencies signature to be like this:

```
private async Task<List<string>> FillAgencies(int id)
{
   var result = new List<string>();
   var municipality =  await _db.Municipality.SingleAsync(s => s.Id == id);
   
   //...add the code for filling the agencies
   
   return result;
}
```

OnGetRetrieveAgencies should look like this

```
public async Task<JsonResult> OnGetRetrieveAgencies(int id)
{
    var agencies = await FillAgencies(id);

    return new JsonResult(agencies);
}
```

In the OnPost method add an await keyword

```
    //if a municipality was selected reload the agencies
    DisplayAgencyName = await FillAgencies(Referral.RefMunicipality);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am reading the link provided and your instructions above, but I am still confused. As far as the onChange event handler. Do you mean something like this? select asp-for="Referral.RefMunicipality" id="Select1" onchange="GetAgencies()" class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplayMuniName.OrderBy(x => x.Name),"Name", "Name"))"><option value="Name" selected disabled>---Select Referring Municipality---</option></select>

Comment: Also, can you please add comments to your code above so I know what each part is referring to? In other words, Why am I getting the municipality? I thought I was getting the agencies? I would already have the municipality from the DD. Where are you getting municipalityId from? Should the 'm' on municipality.AssocAgencies1 etc be capitalized as my model name is capitalized or is this referring to the variable municipality? Like I said, not a programmer and trying to understand what each bit is doing. Thanks!!

Comment: Also,in your above example, shouldn't the ifs be 1,1 and 2,2 not 1,1 and 2,1 for the agencies numbers?

Comment: How would the syntax of the select for the Agency dropdown look? How do I connect it to the list result?

Comment: Can you please share more code? How are you loading the data from the database into the model? I assumed you are using an ORM like Entity Framework. In that case you load all the data for a municipality into the Municipality model. GetMunicipality means LoadMunicipalityInfoFromDB() or something like that depending on your use case.

Comment: Also, you mention you are not a programmer but you are facing the situation of doing a programmer's job. You need to know some basics about ASP.NET and C# to be able to understand how these things work. I recommend reading some books/articles or taking some video tutorials about the basics of ASP.NET, Razor Pages and C#.

Comment: Updated my answer with more complete code examples.  Hope it makes more sense. I understand the position you are in. I encourage you to take it step by step and not become frustrated. Things are not easy at first, but they will become more clear once you understand the concepts.

Comment: I have added your code to my application, but am receiving this error on the .cs page: CS1061 'Municipality' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Municipality' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Can you please explain what it means? It is referring to this line of code: var municipality = await _db.Municipality.Single(s => s.Id == id); - the portion from await and right is underlined.

Comment: Yes, should be SingleAsync since this is an asynchronous call. I modified it. Another topic that I recommend reading when you have time is the async/await mechanism and how it works.

Comment: Thank you. The app will run now, but all I get for the Agency Name is a blank dropdown. Ideas?

Comment: Did you get any error on the client when changing the selection on the municipality drop down list? You can see that by hitting F12 in chrome to open up the developer tools and then reload the page. Follow the console tab.

Comment: First error: Migrate entirely to HTTPS to have cookies sent to same-site subresources and another that says: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at Create:279:9)

Comment: Ok. Here is what it is. Line 279 is this: <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" /> I had an existing section scripts for validation and then you added the additional script. I got an error when I had 2 @section scripts so I put my initial script into the section scripts with yours and apparently VS doesn't like that. How do I properly have 2 section scripts?

Comment: The sections are defined in Layout.cshtml and used in any views that needs them. This is the template for all the views. Can you share the code for the scripts section?

Comment: The script section just had your script above and that one line from the previous script. I did mess up and put one within the other. Trying with it below, but still inside the { } brackets.

Comment: It worked! That was my bad. I didn't realize that I had placed the second script within the </script> of the first script. Thank you so much for all of your help!!!

Comment: Yes, I will. Just one more question. I have required fields on the create page and if the user tries to add the data (ie, post) and they haven't completed a required field, the validation catches it. The problem is, that also resets the Municipality and Agency Name dropdowns to their ---Select--- and if you try to fill them in again they are blank. Ideas on how to correct that?

Comment: Ok, valid point! Let's makes some modifications. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Hi Cristian, I placed the edits where I hope that they go, but my build is failing. I get error CS0103: The name 'municipality' does not exist in the current context" on the "if" lines for getting the AssocAgencies. I also get error CS0019: Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'. and CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int' regarding the else clause on the OnPost. I have added a new .cs above.

Comment: Yes, my bad. It's very hard to replicate your use case since I don't have the database . I've added another edit.

Comment: Hi, I'm not seeing any changes? What am I missing? Also, this confuses me: Why are you adding this? DisplayMuniName = _municipality; if I already had this:         await _db.Referral.Select(a => a.RefMunicipality).ToListAsync();
        DisplayMuniName = await _db.Municipality.ToListAsync();

Comment: I’ve added EDIT 2. I removed the _municipality. I tried to emulate your example by using some local variables instead of the entity framework because that would have been impossible since I don’t have your database and I forgot to remove some of these stuff in the last edit.

Comment: Also, now I’m seeing this message, that’s probably the reason why you are not seeing the latest edit: “Thanks for submitting an edit. It is only visible to you until it’s been approved by trusted community members.”

Comment: Have made your suggested changes, but am returning two errors yet. error CS0019: Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'
CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'

Comment: I hate to ask, but could you put a finished code view in? I am trying to follow through all of your edits and I keep getting errors no matter what I try. I must be missing something. Thanks!